# Timer to ask next question after posting 6 questions in 24hours?

Tags: discussion, support

Is there a timer that indicates when it will be possible to ask the next question after having asked 6 questions in 24hours? Will I be able to post one after 24hours from the last question?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean on the UI of the site, then no, there is no such timer.

You can look at the timestamp of the questions in order to determine how long ago the were asked (hover over the xx minutes/hours ago) - you should be able to ask another one once the oldest of the last 6 questions has gone past 24 hours old.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be able to post one in 3 hours then :)